# Simple switch-off mechanism?

Tags: switches

Electrical engineering isn't my field, so I'm not sure if I even had the right terms for searches thus far. I have a suspicion that there might be an easy way to do what I want to do - or perhaps not.

The situation is, there is a switch A controlling an electrical device. There is another switch B, in this case a tilt switch. The anticipated sequence is, switch A is switched ON; at some time afterwards switch B may be switched ON and at another time after that switched OFF (or vice versa, depending on what works). What I want is for the switch-OFF event at switch B to trigger a solenoid so arranged to switch switch A OFF physically - without the solenoid being triggered the moment switch A is switched ON. I've got the physical action of the solenoid covered.

I would prefer that it be done using discrete components only, due to the design ethic of the overall project. Is it indeed easy?

Comment: It certainly can be done. In fact there are probably several ways it can be done.  What do you mean by design ethic? Do you mean design aesthetic? If so, what's your view on relays, transistors, and basic logic ICs?  Also, a solenoid turning off a switch is unusual... It would be more usual to make A a momentary switch, and use a latching relay. But if a solenoid turning off a switch is what you want that's also doable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The line for choice of technology on this project lies between transistors and logic ICs. It just has to do with the type of thing it is.

The solenoid-off thing is more about ergonomics, though. I need the switch to have clearly separate visible, tactile on and off states, i.e. when it switches off it can be seen to jump to its off position, and your hand will find it there when you next look for it. It's easy: the switch is spring-loaded in the off position and is held in the on position by a spring-loaded detent connected to the solenoid.

Comment: @NedLudd This site is more for questions relating to EE design, and not for asking for design work or opinions on designs. The idea is you ask a specific question that has a specific answer. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  If you go do some research, and come up with a design we will be more than happy to help with questions relating to a specific design. And then you will know how to fix it if it breaks. Thanks

Comment: My apologies. I did not expect design work, but only that someone might know an established, customary way to do what I have in mind, of which I am unaware. My research hitherto has found online sources which are either school-oriented and overly elementary, or so technical that they presume prior knowledge which I lack. Transistor's answer has been hugely helpful and has spared me re-inventing the wheel with doubtless much superfluous complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relay-only answer for the moment but it should get some thinking going on.

*Table 1. Required sequence.*

```
A    B    OUT
0    0     0
1    0     0
1    1     0
1    0     1
0    0     0
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3V6T4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay circuit and timing diagram.*

How it works:

- SWA turns on and powers the circuit.
- If SWB turns on the MEM (the B memory relay) energises and will hold itself on by the MEM contact.
- When SWB turns off power will flow through SWA NO (normally open), SWB NC (normally closed) and MEM NO.
- The solenoid will fire and, presumably switch off whatever turned SWA on. This will cut power to the whole circuit and reset the MEM relay.

The main drawback with the circuit is that it requires a changeover type switch for SWB. If this isn't possible you could add a second relay as shown in Figure 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDPm6s.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Additional relay for single pole tilt switch B. If tilt logic has to be reversed then the RLYB contact can be reversed to suit.*

---

> I don't quite understand: there appears to be a switch marked MEM and a relay marked MEM?

The "switch" is another contact of the MEM relay. We need a second contact to hold the MEM relay on. In this circuit it's acting as a memory that the B switch *was* on. The animation below may help.

[image]

*Figure 3. The concept of the MEM relay is similar to this very common latching relay. An auxiliary contact (that is, not the one powering the load) is used to hold the relay on if the ON button is pressed.*

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't quite understand: there appears to be a switch marked MEM and a relay marked MEM? Is it the same thing, like RLYB in the second example?

Comment: See the update.